# Gulp SASS Task No longer 'Watches' Since Adding Media Queries

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

I had a gulp file which automatically watched my `.JS` and `.SCSS` files and whenever one of these changed, a new compiled version of `all.main.js` and `all.min.css` would be created.

I've since started using breakpoints and media queries, and my gulp task no longer seems to watch the individul `.SCSS` files for changes. If i manually run a gulp SASS, a compiled version is created (so there are no errors).

**Gulpfile:**

```
var paths = {
  js: ['assets/js/app.js', 'assets/js/controllers/*.js', 'assets/js/services/*.js', 'assets/js/directives/*.js'],
  sass: ['assets/css/styles.scss']
};

// SASS task
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src(paths.sass)
      .pipe(sass())
      .pipe(concat('all.min.css'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'));
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {  
    return gulp.src(paths.js)
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(ngannotate())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js/'))
});

// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gutil.log("Watching your files...")        
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('assets/css/*.scss');
    gulp.watch('assets/css/styles.scss');
});

// Default Task
gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'scripts', 'sass', 'watch']);
```

**Styles.scss**

```
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
    @if $point == desktop {
        @media (min-width: 70em) { @content ; }
    }
    @else if $point == laptop {
        @media (min-width: 64em) { @content ; }
    }
    @else if $point == tablet {
        @media (min-width: 50em) { @content ; }
    }
    @else if $point == phablet {
        @media (min-width: 37.5em)  { @content ; }
    }
    @else if $point == mobileonly {
        @media (max-width: 37.5em)  { @content ; }
    }
}

@import "reset.scss";
@import "vars.scss";
@import "header.scss";
@import "home.scss";
@import "images-icons.scss";
@import "utilities.scss";
@import "widths.scss";
```

I can't seem to understand why my SASS task no longer watches my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your configuration wasn't doing anything except running `sass` only when `styles.scss` changed.

Gulp watch needs the files to watch, and the process to run -

```
gulp.watch([source], [task]);
```

Try this below.

```
// Watch Files For Changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gutil.log("Watching your files...")        
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('assets/css/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```